# Android: Adding a new framework

Tags: java, android, makefile

I am trying to add a new framework in Android Source code and call my applications using that framework.

I have included my framework files and called the functions. Makefile for the application includes the new framework. Everything compiles. But when I run my app it force closes. All the Xml layouts and java classes are fine. Manifest file includes

```
<user-library android:name="frameworkName">
```

My question is where to have the mapping for this "frameworkName" in android base code so that it is able to figure out the framework folder/path. Which looks like to be the main problem

What are the possible steps to make this work as I am unable to run my application(Force Close).

EDIT: Initially I was getting Runtime Exception:-Class Not Found for framework classes. Moreover that error was coming up when I missed the "user-library" tag. Now after adding the  tag, my apk is not getting installed by the package manager as it is not able to figure out the the framework path.
Android Developers says this:- "the PackageManager framework won't let the user install the application unless the library is present on the user's device".

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-library-element.html

So which linking am I missing. Any guesses or help would be really helpful for me.

thanks

Comment: Your question is very vague. You should at the very least include the stacktrace for the exception which occurs and ideally provide the relevant code as well.

Comment: @kabuko Its Runtime Exception Class Not Found for framework class. Moreover that error was coming up when I missed the <user-library> tag. 

Now after adding the <user-library> tag, my apk is not getting installed by the package manager as it is not able to figure out the the framework path.

Android Developers says this:-  "the PackageManager framework won't let the user install the application unless the library is present on the user's device"

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "frameworkName", you should put **package name** of your library (the one defined in the application name of your library).

If your classes (and R) are in `com.example.myframework`, then that's your library name.